# Codepen CSS code error for google logo creation

Tags: css

I am trying to create google logo using HTML and CSS.

The code works fine in Browser. However codepen has a problem with the horizontal blue line by not placing it correctly.

How to fix it.

How to change .horizontal-color class property to ensure it works properly in codepen and browser.

Currently this code below is working fine in all browsers.

```
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="color3"></div>
      <div class="right-center-color"></div>
      <div class="horizontal-color"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap"></div>
    <div class="wrap"></div>
  </body>
</html>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #233637;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

html {
  font-size: 125%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
}

.wrap:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
}

.wrap:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 3rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 3rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3rem solid #2ba14b;
  border-left: 3rem solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.wrap:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 3rem solid #e33e2b;
  border-right: 3rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3rem solid transparent;
  border-left: 3rem solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.color3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 3rem solid #e33e2b;
  border-right: 3rem solid transparent;
  border-left: 3rem solid #f1b500;
  border-bottom: 3rem solid #2ba14b;
}

.right-center-color {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 3rem solid #3a7cec;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.horizontal-color {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 8rem;
  background-color: #3a7cec;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Clearly does work in Codepen - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/eYxwprW?editors=1100

Comment: Why do you care if it works in CodePen? That's just a sandbox for testing/demonstrating code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the entire HTML in codepen. That is why it is not working. Just add the body part alone in HTML of codepen. Codepen does not require all of that head section. Once you do that it will work fine.

```
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="color3"></div>
      <div class="right-center-color"></div>
      <div class="horizontal-color"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap"></div>
    <div class="wrap"></div>
  </body>
```